# WPF checkbox twoway binding from property to UI is not working on propertychanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik-grid

I am using twoway binding in a checkbox data column in Telerik Grid view control. when I change the state of checkbox on UI, it is working fine triggering the property changed event. But I also want vice versa, on changing the property value on code behind, the checkbox state should also update on UI.

```
<Button x:Name="btn1" Grid.Row="0" Content="Refresh" Click="btn1_Click" Width="100" Margin="0,5"/>
    <telerik:RadGridView Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="gridView" ShowGroupPanel="False" IsFilteringAllowed="False" SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="70" Header="Color">
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding ChangeValue, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="3"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Data" DataMemberBinding="{Binding dataVal}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
</Grid>
```

The code behind is below

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<Data> dataSource = new List<Data>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            data d = new Data();
            d.DataVal= "Data " + (i + 1);
            dataSource.Add(d);
        }
        this.gridView.SelectedItems.Clear();
        PopulateGridView();
    }
    private void PopulateGridView()
    {
        foreach (Data d in dataSource)
        {
            d.DataVal= false;
        }

        this.gridView.ItemsSource = dataSource;
        List<Data> selectedItems = new List<Data>();
        selectedItems.Add(dataSource[0]);
        this.gridView.Select(selectedItems);
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateGridView();
    }

}

public class Data: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Data()
    {
        DataVal = string.Empty;
    }
    public string DataVal { get; set; }

    public bool ChangeValue
    {
        get { return changevalue; }
        set
        {
            if (value != changevalue)
            {
                changevalue= value;
                if (ApplyPropertyChanged!= null)
                {
                    ApplyPropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ChangeValue"));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private bool changevalue;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler ApplyPropertyChanged;

}
```

On clicking Refresh button I want all checkbox unchecked but they are not updating when I am setting ChangeValue to false in PopulateGridView. Please suggest how can I achieve this.

Comment: How are you able to set `DataVal` to `false`?

Comment: I believe the event should be called `PropertyChanged`, not `ApplyPropertyChanged`. Does this even compile?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify when the UI shoul be updated, in this case onpropertychanged

```
       <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding ChangeValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}" Margin="3"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it still now working with UpdateSourceTrigger.

Comment: the property changed event handler is behaving very weird. if I change the handler name from ApplyPropertyChanged to PropertyChanged then it is working as expected even without using UpdateSourceTrigger. Does anyone has idea why the event handler name could  affect twoway binding?